# Get variable value in if (isset) function outside

Tags: php, global-variables, isset

I am implementing an interface where user should:

1. In **uploadframe.php**. Choose provider;
2. In **upload.php**. Choose & upload files, which are sent to server with `AJAX Request`.

The problem is that I get provider name (very important thing) though `POST` method, and after `AJAX Request`, it returns to **upload.php** page, where provider is not displayed, becuase it is not `isset()` this time. I want to keep the same provider name until I go back to **Uploadframe.php** page and change it there.

**Uploadframe.php:**

```html
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <select name="provider">
        <option value ="activkcell">Activ / Kcell</option>
        <option value ="beeline">Beeline</option>
        <option value ="tele2altel">Tele2 / Altel</option>
    </select>
    <p><input type="file" name="rawexcel[]" id ="rawexcel" multiple> </p>
    <p>
        <input type ="submit" value="Загрузить" name ="submit" id="uplbutton">
    </p>
</form>
```

**Upload.php:**

```php
if (isset($_POST['provider'])) {

    //select action to perform on case of different providers
   if ($_POST['provider'] == 'activkcell') {
       global $provider;
       $provider = "Activ     / Kcell";
   }

   if ($_POST['provider'] == 'beeline') {
       global $provider;
       $provider = "Beeline";
   }

   if ($_POST['provider'] == 'tele2altel') {
       global $provider;
       $provider = "Tele2";
   }
}

<p>You have selected provider <?php global $provider; echo $provider ?></p>
// File selection
// Jjax script
```

I have tried making my `$provider` variable global - did not work, using define ('Provider', $provider)- displays 'Provider' after `ajax request`.

Will appreciate any help. (I do not want to save it somewhere else, like creating a text file and updating it in **uploadframe.php**. I believe there is a solution better than those.)

Comment: try `$_SESSION` that's what it's made for after all.   Please see the Documentation http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php that will help you.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix unfortunately, that is not what I want. One user can/should upload files for different providers

Comment: `$_SESSIONS` is what you are looking for.

Comment: then store them in an array in the session, if you submit a form ( server side ) with that data, return to client, then return back to server side, that is what sessions are for, the  client->sever relationship is stateless, You have to either return the data save it on the client side so you can send it back with the next request, or save it server side in the session so that the next request can access it..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, your `Uploadframe.php` submits the value of `provider` to `upload.php` and on this `upload.php` you make ajax call after user uploads a file and you now need the value of `provider` in the script that handles ajax request.

To do this, send the value of `provider` (that was receieved via $_POST from `Uploadframe.php`) in the ajax request that you make. This way you can still get value of `provider` in `upload.php` when handling AJAX request.